# Variable not read locally error. Cannot figure out why

Tags: java

I am working on a school assignment. The program asks the user for a file name and counts the number of characters, words, and lines in that file. Then asks for the name of the next file. When the user enters the file that doesn't exist, the program prints the total counts of characters, words and lines in all processed files and exists.

So I wrote the program, but I am getting a couple of errors. Here is the counter program, I am getting the error on line

```
private FileCounter counter;
```

and

```
private boolean done;
```

The error says: **The FieldCounter.done is never read locally**.  The same goes for the previous line. I can't figure out why I am getting this warning.

The rest of the program:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.io.FileReader;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    /**
    * A class to count the number of characters, words, and lines in files.
    */

    public class FileCounter
    {
       /**
          Constructs a FileCounter object.
       */
       public FileCounter()
       {
        words = 0;
        lines = 0;
        chars = 0;
        input = "";

     }

       /**
          Processes an input source and adds its character, word, and line
          counts to this counter.
          @param in the scanner to process
       */
       public void read(Scanner in) throws FileNotFoundException
       {

           boolean done = false;
           while (!done)
           {
                 while(in.hasNextLine())
                 {
                   lines++;
                   words++;
                   int j = 0;
                   file = in.nextLine();
                   input = input + file;
                   for(int i = 1; i < file.length(); i++)
                   {
                   if(file.substring(j, i).equals(" "))
                   {
                     words++;
                   }


                   j++;

                }
                  }
                   char[] array = input.toCharArray();
                   int num = array.length;
                   chars += num;
                   if(in.hasNextLine() == false)
                   done = true;
                }



      }
      /**
          Gets the number of words in this counter.
          @return the number of words
       */
       public int getWordCount()
       {
         return words;
      }

       /**
          Gets the number of lines in this counter.
          @return the number of lines
       */
       public int getLineCount()
       {    
          return lines;
       }    

       /**
          Gets the number of characters in this counter.
          @return the number of characters
       */
       public int getCharacterCount()
       {

           return chars;
       }

       private String input;
       private int words;
       private FileCounter counter;
       private int lines;
       private boolean done;
       private int chars;
       private String file;

    }


import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
   This class prints a report on the contents of a number of files.
*/
public class FileAnalyzer
{
   public static void main(String[] args) 
   {  
      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
      FileCounter counter = new FileCounter();
      boolean more = true;
      while (more)
      {
         System.out.print("Please enter the next filename, or <Enter> to quit: ");
         String filename = in.nextLine();
         if (filename.length() > 0)
         {
             try
             {
                 FileReader fileRead = new FileReader(filename);
                 Scanner fileInput = new Scanner(fileRead);
                 counter.read(fileInput);
             }
             catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe)
             {
                 System.out.println("File " + filename + " was not found: " + fnfe);
             }
         }
         else
         {
           more = false;
         }
      }
      System.out.println("Characters: " + counter.getCharacterCount());
      System.out.println("Words: " + counter.getWordCount());
      System.out.println("Lines: " + counter.getLineCount());
   }
}
```

Comment: @PM77-1, thanks I just edited my post to show the error. I was editing while you were commenting.  You guys are way too fast :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a private member variable, `done`, which is never assigned to. Presumably because you declare a local variable `done` in the `read` method and use this. **This is a completely separate variable to `FileCounter.done`**, so `FileCounter.done` will never be used.

Change:

```
boolean done = false;
```

To simply:

```
done = false;
```

You're no longer creating a separate local variable and instead will be using the class' member variable.

Alternatively, remove `private boolean done;` to remove the member variable, but - if you do this - remember that `done` is a local variable and will **not retain its value** across multiple calls to `read` (which is probably what you want in this case, but it's important to understand the distinction).

Answer (score 1):

The warning you are getting means that the variable is essentially useless as it is never read. Remove those lines and all references to them, and in theory you program will still run and no change should happen.

`private boolean done;` this is never used.
`private FileCounter counter;` and so is this.

Answer (score 1):

It is not an error, it is a warning. The program would compile ok, but has found something strange.

In this case you are defining a `private` boolean attribute but you never use it for anything (notice that the `done` that you use in your `read` method is defined locally in the method, so it is a different variable).

Just delete the `private boolean done` line and it will be ok.

The same applies to `counter`.